# Dual homed server routing issue

Tags: networking, routing, persistent

[image]

Have a server running 2012 R2 with a 1Gb network connection and a 10Gb network connection, as well fiber channel connected to an LTO tape library.

Our facility has our closed off Broadcast networks, which have no internet access and then there is our IT's network, which has internet. And there is a firewall sitting between the two.

The 1Gb (`10.120.1.132`) is on the Broadcast network that has firewall rules that allows users to access it from our corporate IT network. Its basically the management port for the server, as it runs a Web GUI for its services.

The 10Gb (`10.120.25.30`) is on the Broadcast network, but no firewall rule for IT and is being used to only transfer data from our Nearline storage to the LTO tape library.

Originally I put the gateway (`10.120.1.1`) only on the 1Gb adapter and created a persistent route for `10.120.25.0` to use gateway `10.120.25.1` and Interface `10.120.25.30`. However, when trying to transfer from Nearline to LTO it was still going over the 1Gb and not using the 10Gb.

Switched the gateways on the NICs, so only the 10Gb has the gateway of `10.120.25.1` and made a persistent route for `10.120.1.0` to use `10.120.1.1` on interface `10.120.1.132`.

Data then goes over the 10Gb to the LTO, however get some not stable behavior when trying to access the webpage through `10.120.1.132` where it won't always connect. (Locally on the server connecting to localhost works fine)

I noticed on the route table that even though there is a persistent route for both `10.120.1.0` and `10.120.25.0` to use their respected gateways, it still has an active route for both of those to use the on-link.
I have other servers with persistent routes and have never seen this where it has both routes on the active route list before.

Correct me if I'm wrong, that shouldn't matter, because of the metric on the persistent routes, but could that be causing the issues where the `10.120.25.0` route originally didn't work and not always being able to access the website through `10.120.1.132` now?